# How to login by email in FOSUserBundle ~2.0@dev?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I tried to change the:

```
providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
```

But nothing happens. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

according to symfony it should be, you missed the security layer. Try adding it:

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
```

Comment: I have added the security layer.

Comment: did it work? if so mark as answered for others to see